# Python dice rolling game stuck on code, want to loop to restart if certain user input is met

Tags: python

So I'm fairly new to this whole coding scene and I'm doing some beginner projects to build upon what I've learned.

- Essentially what I'm trying to do is get the program to restart back at the top of the loop if the user wants to roll again, or accidently types something else that is not "yes" or "no".
- In addition, is there a way to skip a certain line of code, so that way the user isn't asked if they want to roll twice?
- Should I be using functions instead?

Couldn't find any info that helped me directly so thought I would ask, any info at all would be helpful, thanks!

```
import random

useless_varaible1 = 1
useless_varaible2 = 1
# this is the only way I know to set a while loop, I know yikes.
while useless_varaible1 == useless_varaible2:
    lets_play = input('Do you wish to roll? Yes or no: ')
    if lets_play.lower() == 'yes':
        d1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        d2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        ask = input('Do you wish to roll again? ')
        if ask.lower() == 'yes':
            # How do I return to give the user another chance?
        elif ask.lower() == 'no':
            print('Alright, later!')
            break

    elif lets_play.lower() == 'no':
        print('Alright, later!')
        break
    else:
        print('Not any of the options, try again...')
        # how do I return to the top to give the user another chance?
```

([Original code as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkoUn.jpg))

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Instead copy a minimal working example of your code directly into the post. You also have several questions in your post that make it a bit vague/ broad. This way, it's unlikely that you will get a helpful answer. Please also include what you have tried and what problems you encountered.

Comment: Regarding your first question, infinite loops in Python are `while True:`

Comment: I think your code would be a lot simpler if you just kept track of whether the user has already rolled at least once or not.  Then your question at the beginning is either "Do you want to roll?" or "Do you want to roll again?" depending on that question.  After each roll and printout, you just go back to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: As stated by @buddemat, can you just put/paste the code instead of the screenshot of the code?

Comment: @buddemat My bad, first time posting instead of just quick browsing, however, I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 4):

You've asked a couple of questions in one, but I'll try and answer them with an example. First off, to have an infinite running while loop, you can just set it to `True` (basically the same as your `1=1` statement, just easier).

Your second question regarding functions is typically yes - if some code needs to be repeated multiple times, it's usually good to extract it to a function.

Your third question regarding skipping a line of code - easiest way to do this is if/else statements, like you've already done. One thing that can be improved, is by using `continue`; it restarts the loop from the beginning, whereas `break` breaks out of the loop.

Here's a simple code example for your scenario:

```
import random

def roll():
    print('First roll:', random.randint(1, 6))
    print('Second roll:', random.randint(1, 6))

play = input('Do you wish to roll? Yes or no: \n')

while True:
    if play.lower() == 'yes':
        roll()
        play = input('Do you wish to roll again? \n')
    elif play.lower() == 'no':
        print('Alright, later!')
        break
    else:
        play = input('Not any of the options, try again... Yes or no: \n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I would do it like this

```
import random
useless_variable = 1
lets_play = input("Do you want to roll. yes or no: ")
if lets_play.lower() == "yes":
    while useless_variable == 1:
        useless_variable == 0
        d1 = random.randint(1,6)
        d2 = random.randint(1,6)
        print("You got a: ", d1, "from the first dice")
        print("You got a: ", d2, "from the seond dice")
        ask = input("Wanna roll again(yes or no):")
        if ask.lower() == "yes":
            useless_variable = 1
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an infinite loop then `while True:` Otherwise you can put in your while something like `while condition == true` and in your answer when is "no" change the condition to false.

I would do it like this

```
def roll():
   if(lets_play.lower() == "yes"):
      //Code here
   elif lets_play.lower() == "no":
      //Code here   
   else:
      print("invalid")

while True:
   lets_play = input("Roll?")   
   if lets_play.lower() == "exit":
      break
   else:
      roll()
```